# SvelteKit root-route not working but sub-routes work | adapter-static with paths.base configuration

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I used SvelteKit to build a little trip journal app. With `adapter-static` and `prerender = true; ssr = false`, to deploy on gitlab pages.

On gitlab pages, navigating to a specific page works. But at the root `index.html`, it won't load any scripts or assets from `%sveltekit.head%`, as the base path is duplicated. Pointing to `./repo/repo/_app/...` instead of `./_app/...` as the sub-pages do.

The same issue can be found in a Discord message on the SvelteKit server [here](https://discord.com/channels/457912077277855764/1080511694310232064/1081720125729800233)

My `svelte.config.js` looks like this.

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

const dev = process.argv.includes('dev');
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown. On some platforms
            // these options are set automatically — see below
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: null,
            precompress: false,
            strict: true
        }),
        paths: {
            base: dev ? '' : '/backfuel'
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

This is the repo: [dscham/backfuel](https://gitlab.com/dscham/backfuel)